# how to write a makefile to run pylint?

Tags: makefile, pylint

I have always been a windows user and this is my first time using solaris, so don't assume I know anything about shell scripts. lets say I have some 3 different python program in a folder.

$:pwd

/pythonpgm

$:ls

1.py
2.py
3.py

I am using pylint to staticlly analyze my code

$:pylint -rn 1.py

Instead of using it individually on each file, I want to write a Makefile so that I have to do this only once. How to write a makefile for this? and call make?

Answer (score 7):

Using your editor, create a file called `Makefile` in your current directory and put this in it:

```
pylint: ; @for py in *.py; do echo "Linting $$py"; pylint -rn $$py; done
```

Now you just run `make`.

That's about as simple as it gets.  If you want something more sophisticated, you can use:

```
PYLINT = pylint
PYLINTFLAGS = -rn

PYTHONFILES := $(wildcard *.py)

pylint: $(patsubst %.py,%.pylint,$(PYTHONFILES))

%.pylint:
        $(PYLINT) $(PYLINTFLAGS) $*.py
```

(note, the first character on the last line above *MUST BE* a real TAB character, it cannot be spaces).  The advantage to this one is you can run `make 1.pylint` to just run pylint on the single file `1.py`, or run `make` to run it on all files.